# Any cleaner or alternate way to write sql join script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

I have following tables:

```
 Table2       
 StudentNumbers  ExamType
 ------------------------
           1234         1
           2343         2   
           3345         5
           3454         1
           5465         2
            ...

 Table1   
 StudentNumbers  ExamType   ExamDate  School  Area             Info
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
           1234         1       0825  warren    ny    0x504B03042D0
           1234         1       0829   north    nj    0x63D86E1FFFF
           1233         2       0921   north    nj    0xA001400646F
           2343         1       0922  warren    ny    0x01400646174
           2343         1       0925   north    ny    0x100100070se
            ...
```

I am trying to write a query to get following results:

```
StudentNumbers  ExamType   ExamDate  School  Area            Info
-----------------------------------------------------------------
          1234         1       0829   north    nj   0x63D86E1FFFF
          2343         1       0925   north    ny   0x100100070se
```

I wrote following query:

```
Select t1.StudentNumbers, t1.ExamDate, t1.School, t1.Info, t1.ExamType        
from Table1 as t1
  Join(
       Select ts.StudentNumbers, max(ts.ExamDate) as ExamDate
       from Table2 as ts
         Join Table1 as pl on 
           ts.StudentNumbers = pl.StudentNumbers where ts.ExamType = pl.ExamType
       group by ts.StudentNumbers
       ) as t2 on t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers
                    and t1.ExamDate = t2.ExamDate
```

Above query works and gives me the result i want that is max ExamDate for particular ExamType based on Table2. But is using multiple joins best way in this aggregate method? Or is there a cleaner option.

Comment: Well I would say that it's the `ANSI SQL` way, which is fine. You may find other options depending on your dbms, but... you don't tell us which one you use.

Comment: so your question is not about joins but rather on "improving"/changing your query?

Comment: btw..which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `table2` seems unnecessary as the same information (`studentNumber/ExampType`)  is available in table1 as well (although they don't really match in your example)

Comment: You also say you want "max examDate for a particular ExamType", yet your `max()` aggregate calculates the max. examDate *per student* not per examType.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - I am using sql 2008.

Comment: @JafarKofahi - Using sql server 2008 and yes question is this right way to do this query? Or is there a better and more cleaner way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I need table2 as information i want from table1 should be coming from table2 itself. Like table 2 will tell me which Students i want to show up in 3rd table and i want the max or most recent exam date of those students.

Comment: which indexes you are using?

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko - Not using any indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is good, but I think to use Table2 table outside subquery would be better option.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT StudentNumbers, ExamType, MAX(ExamDate) AS ExamDate
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY StudentNumbers, ExamType
      ) t1 JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers
             AND t1.ExamType = t2.ExamType AND t1.ExamDate = t2.ExamDate
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM Table2 t3
             WHERE t1.StudentNumbers = t3.StudentNumbers
               AND t1.ExamType = t3.ExamType
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.StudentNumbers = t2.StudentNumbers
WHERE t1.ExamDate = (SELECT MAX(ExamDate) FROM Table1 WHERE StudentNumbers = t1.StudentNumbers)
ORDER BY t1.StudentNumbers ASC
```

Might not be the most efficient solution though.